# Efficiency issue with Excel VBA loop

Tags: excel, vba

I need to go over a data with a few thousand lines and edit specific rows based on values of a few fields (if they meet some criteria).

The problem is that it takes ages (~13 seconds per loop, sometimes I have 100 loops)... I tried also to make VBA filter the table then work on filtered rows but it took the same time.

```
While l < CurrAloc And k <= lastrow
  If Cells(k, g) = "Pass" And Cells(k, h) <> "" And Cells(k, i) = "" And Cells(k, j) = "Available" Then

    Cells(k, ULDecCol) = CurrCustomer
    Cells(k, ULFromClassifierCol) = CurrClassifier
    add_to_log k
    Sheets("Unit List").Select
    l = l + 1
  End If

  k = k + 1
Wend
```

Comment: is it your entire code ? you have `Sheets("Unit List").Select` inside your loop, which is scanning thousands of lines as you say, and I am not sure what are you doing with this Select. `Select` takes a lot of time.

Comment: ~13 secs is a lot. You shouldnt encounter performance problems with a single loop like that. Maybe you have a problem with your `add_to_log`? How long does it take if you dont write that log? If you use Selecting of a different sheet in you log: try to write to that sheet without selecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

before the while loop followed by

`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`

After the end of the while loop.

Comment: It's so basic I'm honestly a little bit embarrassed :) Thanks!